# Why are the grid_scores_ higher than the score for full training set? (sklearn, Python, GridSearchCV)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm building a logistic regression model as follows:

```
cross_validation_object = cross_validation.StratifiedKFold(Y, n_folds = 10)
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = [0,1])
logistic_fit = LogisticRegression()

pipeline_object = Pipeline([('scaler', scaler),('model', logistic_fit)])

tuned_parameters = [{'model__C': [0.01,0.1,1,10],
                    'model__penalty': ['l1','l2']}]

grid_search_object = GridSearchCV(pipeline_object, tuned_parameters, cv = cross_validation_object, scoring = 'roc_auc')
```

I looked at the roc_auc score for the best estimator:

```
grid_search_object.best_score_
Out[195]: 0.94505225726738229
```

However, when I used the best estimator to score the full training set, I got a worse score:

```
grid_search_object.best_estimator_.score(X,Y)
Out[196]: 0.89636762322433028
```

How can this be?  What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Nevermind.  I'm an idiot.  grid_search_object.best_estimator_.score calculates accuracy, not auc_roc.  Right?

But if that is the case, how does GridSearchCV compute the grid_scores_?  Does it pick the best decision threshold for each parameter, or is the decision threshold always at 0.5?  For area under the ROC curve, decision threshold doesn't matter, but it does for say, f1_score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you evaluated the `best_estimator_` on the full training set it is not surprising that the scores are different from the `best_score_`, even if the scoring methods are the same:

The `best_score_` is the average over your cross-validation fold scores of the best model (best in exactly that sense: scores highest on average over folds).

When scoring on the whole training set, your score may be higher or lower than this. Especially if you have some sort of temporal structure in your data and you are using the wrong data splitting, scores on the full set can be worse.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I think here the problem is that best_estimator_ was calculated by maximizing the roc_auc.  Hence, the grid_scores_ all reflect the area under the ROC curve.  Later, when I applied best_estimator_, sklearn gave me the accuracy.

Comment: Ah, I see -- I didn't scroll far enough to the right to see that in your code and was thus wondering where your edit came from. OK -- what happens if you don't set scoring, or explicitly set it to accuracy? (Or is this ill-advised due to strong class imbalance in your data?) I think the results should still differ.

Comment: as for the decision threshold: it is fixed, since the optimization should have found the right intercept to make it fit.

Comment: Ok, so basically if I use f1_score, the optimization will use the best decision threshold for each set of parameters?

Comment: The scorers such as `roc_auc` utilize the `predict_proba` method to have continuous values which to threshold at different points to make the roc curve. The estimator itself doesn't move this threshold explicitly for decision. Implicitly it is set by fitting the right intercept.